# What does "shades" mean?

Tags: meaning, emoticons

Quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons, here is an explanation of some emoticons:

> 8-)   shades

I was wondering what does "shades" mean here? Does it mean smile?

Comment: I think it's off-topic

Comment: I would say that it is on-topic, as it is asking the meaning of a word; it would eventually be a "general reference," but I am not sure I would close it for that reason. It is not even true it is too localized.

Comment: This is general reference. One link: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/shades?q=shades

Comment: @Mahnax: how is somebody who doesn't know that *shades* means sunglasses supposed to guess that the emoticon means *cool*?  Maybe he uses them to protect his eyes from the sun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 8-) Emoticon represents a smiling face wearing sunglasses (shades is an informal word for sunglasses as mentioned above).  The emoticon is taken to refer to the context being 'cool' (informal for good).

Comment: +1 for giving the answer that was needed rather than the literal one.

Comment: I don't generally use these "exotic" smileys, but to be honest I'd have been more likely to interpret this one as [boffin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boffin) (scientists are often stereotyped as wearing thick pebble-glasses). So I'd assume it meant something along the lines of *"Whatever I wrote before this smiley should be interpreted as having come from a person who knows the technical details of what he's talking about"*

Comment: However when rendered by message boards (IPB, phpBB & vBulletin) in addition to Skype and MSN messenger the 8-) emoticon is always shown to be a smiling face wearing black **opaque** sunglasses.  This doesn't really fit with the 'boffin' concept, which I believe is not correct =)

Answer (score 5):

*Shades* is an informal word for *sunglasses*. That is what that smiley should remind of: the face of a person wearing sunglasses.

Comment: Thanks! What kind of emotion does 8-) mean?

Comment: I generally see it used to mean "I am cool!"